# How to download and store images to not be cleared by device later?

Tags: trigger.io

I have an application which downloads its product data(descipttions and images) from server and stores them localy to be available offline. For product images I'm using forge.file.cacheURL which works great but on my iPAD, this cache is being cleared during the day when I work with another apps. This causes my application to have only descipription texts available without images and user must connect to internet and synchronize again what is quite annoying. Is there a better way how to implement this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use the `forge.prefs` module for this purpose? It allows you so persistantly save key-value-pairs locally (much like HTML5 localstorage). Read more about the exact syntax in Trigger.io's [official API documentation](http://docs.trigger.io/en/latest/modules/prefs.html).

I'm not quite sure whether its possible to save images with this method, but you could easily transform your images into strings and vice-versa. Check out the second chapter of this post by Robert Nyman on how to [save images in localStorage](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/).

Comment: I'm using forge.prefs for storing product descriptions and other text information but as I know its not suitable for binary format / images.

Comment: Have a look at the second link in my answer. It includes a section about saving images in localStorage and describes how to convert an image into a string and vice-versa using a canvas element.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, this gave me a hint! I have encoded images into base64 and stored them in forge.pref as strings for each product and adjusted img urls accordingly http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme , seems to be working on both ... iOS and Android.